# Resize Controls using default, Dock, Anchor and AutoGrow. C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Let's say I have this layout

[image]

Depending on the form size, I want to make the controls grow/shrink while maintaining the base structure. Like this:

In the example, the black area should grow bigger while the white area should stay the same when you grow the border.

A more detailed description should be that the control should grow at a 1/4 rate of the border and if it's not in the same row should move along the growth.

My question is: Is it possible to do it with only properties?

Currently, I have a function that does the resizing but it lags a lot and I'm trying to find a better solution. Any suggestions?

(Using Winforms and .NET 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the `TableLayoutPanel` control. If I'm interpreting your image correctly, you would have a `TableLayoutPanel` with its `Dock` set to `Fill`. You would then add one row and seven columns. The first, third, fifth and seventh columns would all have a width of 25% and the second, fourth and sixth columns would the appropriate absolute widths. You can then add controls to the proportional columns and set their `Dock` to `Fill` so they fill their cell in the `TableLayoutPanel`.